# Ways to parse this Back4App JSON data

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having some trouble parsing this JSON data it's a data set from Back4App on vehicle year make and models.
This is a sample of JSON I have

```
{
"results": [
 {
   "objectId": "FDAAV1X9xE",
   "Year": 2019,
   "Make": "Toyota",
   "Model": "4Runner",
   "createdAt": "2020-01-27T20:44:18.152Z",
   "updatedAt": "2020-01-27T20:44:18.152Z"
 }
}
```

This is what I have for now:

```
struct CarObject: Decodable {
    var Year: String
    var Make: String
    var Model: String
}

struct jResult: Decodable {
    var results: Array<CarObject>
}
```

This is how I fetch from the URL and I just set a @State variable:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            func addToMakes(val: String) {
                if (!changeVal.contains(val)) {
                    changeVal.append(val)
                }
            }
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let jsonResult = try decoder.decode(jResult.self, from: data!)
                print(jsonResult.results[1].Make)
                for i in 1...jsonResult.results.count-1 {
                    addToMakes(val: jsonResult.results[i].Make)
                }
            } catch {
                fatalError("Couldn't parse \(error)")
            }
        }).resume()
```

This doesn't work it gives me this error, do you guys have a better idea on how to fetch this data?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what error do you get? Try to adding `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))`
 just before `let decoder = JSONDecoder()` and show us what you get.

Comment: Have a close look at the JSON. Hint: The value for key `Year` is not in double quotes

Comment: "This doesn't work it gives me this error" What error? I'm saying this, because I guess it has information useful to understand why it failed...

Comment: @vadian is so right – and: the json is missing a closing  `]`

Comment: Two invaluable websites when starting to decode JSON data: [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) & [Quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io). QuickType helps you come up with your decoding structure. It can be a bit verbose as it can only go by the data you give it, but you will learn how to format your decodable structs from it.

Comment: @Yrb Thanks for that it showed me what's the right way to make the Codable structs. Everything works fine! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Look out cat the carObject structure, you have the year parameter as a string and in the json it's an int

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).